# MongoDB - Update within a list that is inside another list

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to do an update the next mongodb document, `approved` field is a list that is inside another list

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("580b914d240a4974188ef35f"),
    "name" : "Test1",
    "action" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("580b914d240a4974188ef360"),
                "desc": "Test2"
                "approved" : [ ]
            }
    ],
}
```

Follows the mongoosejs the code I'm using.

He finds the document but not doing the update, if I use the find is the document found.

```
User.update({"action._id": id},
    {"$push": {
        "action.approved": {desc: "Test update"}
        }
    },
    function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                obj: err
            });
        }
        return res.status(202).json({
            obj: doc,
        })
})
```

Using the `find` the document is found.

```
User.find({"action._id": id},
    function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                obj: err
            });
        }
        return res.status(202).json({
            obj: doc,
        })
})
```

They could help me to make to the update?

Thank you.

Comment: Use the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/positional/) `{"$push": {
        "action.$.approved": {desc: "Test update"}
        }
    }`

Comment: Thank you  @chridam worked perfectly!!!!